# Magento 1.9 Import: “Invalid image file type.”

Tags: magento-1.9, import, url, product-images, external

Ref:[1]: [Magento 1.7 Import: "Invalid image file type."](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73982/magento-1-7-import-invalid-image-file-type/122471#122471)

I am also having the same issue `invalid image file type`. I am trying to import product images from external url.. while importing the csv file, blank files created inside the media/import folder. And shows error `a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c. [extension] => [filename] => a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c ){"savedRows":0,"errors":["Invalid image file type."]}`. Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.7 Import: "Invalid image file type."](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73982/magento-1-7-import-invalid-image-file-type)

Answer (score 0):

Is it only happening with some of the images or all of them ? If only to a part of them, change them from JPG to PNG, should do the trick. PNG is much lighter and more friendly to Magento.

Comment: no.. its happening with all of the images

Comment: I tried png images too... But all the files are stored in media/import  folder like  a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c. file extension is not coming...help me to solve the issue

Comment: @Sruthi what do you mean by "file extension is not coming up"?

Comment: files are storing in media/import like a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c.

Comment: @Sruthi and by that you don't know which file is for which product ?

Comment: I am trying to import product images using sku

Comment: Yeah I do the same, so when you upload them, their name changes ?

Comment: yes.. I thought its encrypted name..

Comment: Tried to import with excel ? do a VLOOKUP on SKU, and put the external image URL into the different image columns of the excel, and then import the excel.

Comment: its not working...

Comment: I downloaded all the images to import folder... then tried to import product images.. its also not working.. getting same errorr `invalid image file type`